# How to crop, trim video?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

How to crop, trim video in macOS environment using Apple or non-Apple library?
Want to simply select the area on the screen and crop the video at the selected area and create a new video from it.
Got a library for this task in iOS, but couldn't found for macOS project

similar iOS Project: https://github.com/prynt/PryntTrimmerView

No prior knowledge of video editing, it would be great if you can provide sample code.

Comment: Official Apple sample code for it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 4):

UI wise, first you'll need to implement some kind of slider/scrubber to select the range you want to trim.

Then for actually cropping the video, you should take a look at [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/)

Specifically at **AVMutableVideoComposition** and  **AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction** you can give then instructions on how to handle your video output.

For cropping:

```
  let videolayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: asset)

 videolayerInstruction.setCropRectangle(CGRec(), at: Time())
```

For trimming:

```
let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
 composition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30) (30 is a frame rate here)
```